# Why does weblogic not use my deployment plan?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am having some trouble trying to adjust the deployment settings of our application in weblogic.  I feel what I'm trying to do ought to be quite simple, but it's not working as expected.

I am just trying to override the context-root in weblogic.xml and the JNDI name for the data source, so these can both be configured at deployment time.

I have removed the application.xml from the ear file, so that shouldn't be affecting the overrides.

What I have so far:

weblogic.xml:

```
<context-root>mosaic</context-root>

<resource-description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/LogicalDS</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>LogicalDS</jndi-name>
</resource-description>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>A logical reference to the datasource - mapped in deployment plan</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/LogicalDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

plan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <wls:deployment-plan xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan/1.0/deployment-plan.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/j2ee_1_4.xsd" global-variables="true">
 <!--weblogic-version:10.3.5-->
 <wls:application-name>mosaic.ear</wls:application-name>
 <wls:variable-definition>
    <wls:variable>
        <wls:name>datasource_name</wls:name>
        <wls:value xsi:nil="true"></wls:value>
        <wls:description>The name of the datasource to map to the mosaic application</wls:description>
    </wls:variable>
    <wls:variable>
        <wls:name>new_context_root</wls:name>
        <wls:value xsi:nil="true"></wls:value>
        <wls:description>URL to deploy Mosaic at</wls:description>
    </wls:variable>
 </wls:variable-definition>
<wls:module-override>
    <wls:module-name>mosaic.war</wls:module-name>
    <wls:module-type>war</wls:module-type>
    <wls:module-descriptor>
        <wls:root-element>weblogic-web-app</wls:root-element>
        <wls:uri>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</wls:uri>
        <wls:variable-assignment>
            <wls:name>new_context_root</wls:name>
            <wls:xpath>/weblogic-web-app/context-root</wls:xpath>
            <wls:operation>replace</wls:operation>
        </wls:variable-assignment>
        <wls:variable-assignment>
            <wls:description>Data source for mosaic application</wls:description>
            <wls:name>datasource_name</wls:name>
            <wls:xpath>/weblogic-web-app/resource-env-description/resource-env-ref-name</wls:xpath>
            <wls:operation>replace</wls:operation>
        </wls:variable-assignment>
        <wls:variable-assignment>
            <wls:name>datasource_name</wls:name>
            <wls:xpath>/weblogic-web-app/resource-description/[res-ref-name="jdbc/LogicalDS"]/jndi-name</wls:xpath>
            <wls:operation>replace</wls:operation>
        </wls:variable-assignment>
    </wls:module-descriptor>
  </wls:module-override>
</wls:deployment-plan>
```

Nothing happens when I use the deployment plan, and none of the variables appear under the Deployment Plan configuration screens in the admin console.  From what I understand, I should at least be asked for these variables, since I have specified that they are null in the deployment plan.

When I use WLST to browse the tree, I find that the runtime configuration just stays as the values in the deployment descriptors.

I have verified the deployment plan is being used in the general tab of the admin console.

Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: I never got it to appear in the console. (Well perhaps years ago). Try removing the `xsi:nil` and supply a value, it will pick it up even when you don't see it in the admin console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have "datasource_name" variable replacement twice.  Is that intended?  Your xpath appears to be incorrect:

resource-description/[res-ref-name=
etc.

Should it be:

resource-description[res-ref-name=
etc.

My suggestion is to change one thing at at time, for example, the web app context first, and test.  The web app context can be also set in the admin console, so you should see the value there.

There are few good articles about deployment plan:

https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/11gr1_update_and_a_deployment

http://m-button.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-use-deployment-plan.html

A good resource mapping doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13737/packagedjdbc.htm
 (look for the diagram near the bottom).

Is your variable a "replace" or "define"?